# Count the number of neutral, positive and neutral tweets from database and update table accordingly

Tags: mysql

Consider the following tables

```
users                    tweets
--------------------     -----------------------------
user_id  neu pos neg     id _date       user_id  class
--------------------     -----------------------------
1                        1  2011-02-13  1        1
2                        2  2011-02-13  1        2
                         3  2011-02-15  2        1
                         4  2011-02-16  2        3
                         5  2011-02-16  2        3
```

Each tweet in the database has been analyzed and classified. `tweets.class` can be either `1` (neutral), `2` (positive) or `3` (negative). I need a query to count all `neu` (neutral, `pos` (positive) and `neg` (negative) tweets per user. The end result of the query would be and `UPDATE`d `users`-table like so:

```
users
--------------------
user_id  neu pos neg
--------------------
1        1   1   0
2        1   0   3
```

I now have but this doesn't work at all. Am a going into the right direction?

```
update users u left join (
  select count(t.id) as neu from tweets t where class = 1 
) on u.user_id = t.user_id
set u.neu = coalesce(neu,0)
```

Comment: try update query from my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

```
UPDATE users a
       INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id,
                          SUM(IF(class = 1, 1, 0)) AS class_1,
                          SUM(IF(class = 2, 1, 0)) AS class_2,
                          SUM(IF(class = 3, 1, 0)) AS class_3
                   FROM tweets
                   GROUP BY user_id
                 ) b
             ON a.user_id = b.user_id
SET a.neu = b.class_1,
    a.pos = b.class_2,
    a.neg = b.class_3;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. MySQL returns `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT user_id, SUM(IF(class = 1, 1, 0)) AS class_1, ' at line 2` Shouldn't the `SELECT` be joined to the `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: `76456 row(s) affected. ( Query took 28.9183 sec )` Here's some karma :-)